# Show subdomains in apache logs

Tags: apache, subdomain, logging

I would like the subdomains to show up in the my apache logs.

At the moment a request for:

```
abc.website.com/doc1.html
def.website.com/doc2.html
```

show up in my logs only as:

```
/doc1.html
/doc2.html
```

I was looking for an option at:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

but i found nothing related to the subdomains.

(Pleas excuse my English.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a %V in your LogFormat line, for example:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" %V"
```